# Sitecore 8: GEO-IP not picking up UK visitors

Tags: sitecore, geoip, sitecore8

When I view details of users who visit the site from Sri Lanka in Sitecore Experience Explorer City, Region and Country is getting populated. However when I check an user who visit the site from UK, above fields are not being populated.
Geo-Ip service is running on the App Centre.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tested the Maxmind service using the TestIp.aspx from https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498 in Solution 3.
When I use Sri Lankan IP address it getting the details.
But when I use a UK IP address it won't getting the details.

I have set the 'Access for unspecified clients' to true from IIS.

Comment: Which geolocation service provider you are using in Sitescore? IP2Location or Maxmind?

Comment: Sitecore using Maxmind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for getting this problem is our QA in UK, visits the site from the internal network (the same network the website is hosted). Geo IP not tracking City, Region and Country for the visitors who visiting the site in the same network (internal network).

You can check the functionality of this by visiting the site from outside your network. You can use an IP changing tool like Hide My Ass or Freedom to change your IP and visit the site as an external user.